# EnhancedGrid not displaying all the rows in Google Chrome

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

I have a EnhancedGrid displaying random number of rows. (Number of rows depend on the data fetched from DB). When loaded for the first time, if the grid has more than 10-12 rows, last 3 rows are not getting displayed in the grid. when I checked the browser console, the data is properly returned in Json string. when I select the last displayed row in the grid and then press "Down" key on keyboard, remaining records get displayed in the grid. This happens only in Google chrome browser. It works perfectly fine in IE.

Below is my declaration of enhanced grid.

```
this._myGrid = new EnhancedGrid({
            id: "dataGrid",
            noDataMessage:this.messages.no_results_were_found,
            errorMessage:this.messages.grid_error_message
        }, document.createElement('div'));
```

anybody has faced such error before? any pointer would be really appreciated.

Comment: I would recommend moving from `EnhancedGrid` to one of it's two successors: `dgrid` and `gridx`.

Answer (score 0):

Put the widget inside a dojo content pane, it will add a scroll if the child widget need more space.

One big cause for you problem that I see is that you are putting a dojo widget (whose height may vary) inside a html div